# Undefined reference. DSO missing

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile qt ffmpeg wrapper simple encoding/decoding example under linux [QTFFmpegWrapper source](https://code.google.com/p/qtffmpegwrapper/downloads/list)

```
# Set list of required FFmpeg libraries .pro file
LIBS += -lswresample \
    -lavcodec \
    -lavformat \
    -lavutil \
    -lswscale \
    -lz
```

Compiling failed due to error
:-1: error: /home/mher/Qt5.4.0/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libavformat.a(avisynth.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2:-1: error: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

I found similar situation [DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096807/dso-missing-from-command-line) here. Should I set run settings? Or need to change .pro file?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the line: `LIBS += -ldl` in your pro file.

Comment: Nothing changed. Can compile error be caused by dynamic loader?

Comment: Did you do `make clean; make distclean; qmake <src_dir>; make` ?

Comment: No. I just do clean all, run qmake, rebuild from qt creator

Comment: Some versions of `QtCreator` had a problem with that, that's why I am talking you what exactly you need to do. Try do to that.

Comment: After doing as You said I've got

../../QTFFmpegWrapper/QVideoEncoder.cpp:113:37: error: ‘avcodec_thread_init’ was not declared in this scope
    avcodec_thread_init(pCodecCtx, 10);
../../QTFFmpegWrapper/QVideoEncoder.cpp:125:42: error: ‘av_set_parameters’ was not declared in this scope
    if (av_set_parameters(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0)

Comment: @MherDidaryan [Google it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024843/errors-while-installing-opencv-and-ffmpeg-through-rightscripts)